# Swift - Scrollview Starting from Middle in iPhone 5s

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I have used the ScrollView in my Home Screen in App:

The scrollView seems to be normal in all other devices, except when i run it any smaller devices like **iPhone 5s**.

> It does not start from the Top, See in the this iPhone5s

[image]

> But it works correctly in bigger devices like **iPhone 7**

[image]

**Note:-** I have used following suggestions from other Answers.

**Setting ScrollView Content offset**

```
scrollViewDashboard.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)
scrollViewDashboard.contentOffset = .zero
```

Any Help would be Appreciated.

Comment: Try `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets  =  false` in view did load

Comment: @K.Walid I have used that correctly I guess, As the scrolling works perfectly , the thing is only for 5s it starts from middle.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya it did not worked for me.Any other suggestions from you end.?
"

Comment: Are you using autolayout ?

Comment: Yes @PrashantTukadiya yes i am using that.

Comment: You are talking about that popover view that it is not on top correct ? , How you are finding  that position to show hide ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168837/discussion-between-abhirajsinh-thakore-and-prashant-tukadiya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same problem previously, try setting your offsets in

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
scrollViewDashboard.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It should be false because of if we set true then move up the screen with animation.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
scrollViewDashboard.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
}
```